# Android Уровень аппаратной абстракции (HAL)

Tags: android, root

У меня такой вопрос есть Android 11 с root правами, можно ли считать пиксели на экране с одного участка и отображать их на другом участке ,не зависимо какая программа работает на уровне Hardware abstraction layer (HAL) , ну к примеру читать участок на экране `(0 px,0 px, 200 px , 200 px)`  и отобразить это на участке экрана  `(0 px,400 px, 200 px , 200 px)`.